# Get specific JSON data value using array from Coin Market Cap API

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, api, ethereum

I want to get the symbol and other information using the "name" in my array.

```
$.getJSON("//api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0", function(data) {

    var crypto = [
      "Ethereum",
      "Ripple",
      "Tron", 
    ];

    // used for array to get length
    var arrayLength = crypto.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        console.log( data[i].name == crypto[i] );
    }
  });
```

I've tried to use:

`console.log( data[i].name == crypto[i] );`

but can't get this to work. As of now it lists everything when I only want to list data from the items in my array.

I want to get the data in the array using the name to retrieve its information from the API.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use inArray function.

**example:**

```
$.getJSON("//api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0", function(data) {

    var crypto = [
      "Ethereum",
      "Ripple",
      "Tron", 
    ];

    // used for array to get length
    var arrayLength = crypto.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(jQuery.inArray(data[i].name, crypto) !== -1)
            console.log('Finded: ' + data[i].name);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can also add the use of `$.each()` instead of a for loop

Comment: this is super helpful.

Comment: Would the proper way be, adding `{` `}` to the `if` statement?

`for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(jQuery.inArray(data[i].name, crypto) !== -1) {
            console.log('Finded: ' + data[i].name);
         }
    }`